# Uber Accept Surge Confirmation from Server

Tags: php, uber-api

By my understanding when Uber turns a Surge Confirmation request with response code 409, it wants the user to visit the provided link and in some way act to confirm that the surge pricing is OK.

I am wondering, is it possible to confirm acceptance of a surge without the need of a user to visit the provided URL?

I am accessing the Uber API via PHP, so in essence, can I get the PHP server to process this acceptance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to accept the surge confirmation without prompting the user with the provided URL.